# i have slap command in my discord bot written in python. Can somebody tell me how to make oportunity type ID instead of ping?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I made this command possible to use only by ping, but i don't know how to add oportunity to use member ID.

Here is code, that i already have:

```
@Bot.command()
async def slap( ctx, member : discord.Member ):
    emb = discord.Embed(title=None, description = f"For the whole chat there was a noise from a {ctx.author.mention} slap {member.mention} in the face!", color=0x3498db)
    await ctx.send( embed = emb )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do do this using `guild.get_member(ID)`.

btw your command should work also with fullname#tag like `slap AZ#0573` instead of mention

```py
@Bot.command()
async def slap(ctx, member_id:int):
    member = ctx.guild.get_member(member_id)
    emb = discord.Embed(title=None, description = f"For the whole chat there was a noise from a {ctx.author.mention} slap {member.mention} in the face!", color=0x3498db)
    await ctx.send( embed = emb )
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work, because member = None (always). And i don't understand why.

Comment: It says :"from a (for example) selion  slap none". And member.mention doesn't work too.

Comment: Sorry completely my bad i misspelled member for `membed`. Fixed it.

Comment: no, i saw that already and fixed but it doesn't work. There is just error, that member is always = None so "{member.mention}" doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that the member is a part of the guild? because it is working for me.

Comment: yeah, i am sure. I'll try again

Comment: i tried again and it didn't work even when i copied and past your code.

Comment: How are you getting the member ID? right click and copy ID?

Comment: i figuered, that i had wrong version of discord.py library, your method works, i am sorry

Answer (score 0):

I have a code that slaps when you mention someone instead of using their ID.

```
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 2, commands.BucketType.user)
async def slap(ctx, member:discord.User=None):
  if (member == ctx.message.author or member == None):
      await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention} slaps themselves!") 
  else:
      await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention} slaps {member.mention}!")
```